# How to stop "Next" button replacing "Go" button on android 7 soft keyboard while focusing an input of asp website

Tags: android, asp.net, forms, input, focus

When I focus on an input of the website on some browsers in Android 7 (Chrome, Firefox...), the "Go" button was replaced by "Next" button. It will be helpful for the form have multiple fields but it's terrible for the asp website, because there is only one form tag in the whole page. It means when I have multiple form in a page, it just moves the focus from this form to another form when I click the "Go/Next" button instead of submitting the form.

Do we have any attribute for the input to ask the OS stop replacing the "Go" button?

Best regards,

Hanh Dang

Answer (score 0):

If you set `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` the button will be rendered as a <s>`<button>`</s> `<input type='button'>` element with JavaScript that causes the postback (instead of a `<input type='submit'>` element) and this may be enough to trick the Android browser (btw which browser are you using?) into thinking there is no way to submit the form and it not display the Go button for the last form entry box.

**Edit**

I see your comment that this did not work. Depending on the type of JavaScript framework you are using you may be able to code a traditional `<button>` (or anything else like `<a class='btn'>`) and use [`GetPostBackEventReference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate the code to manually initiate a postback (or just call `__doPostBack` - not recommended but hey, this is old asp.net, right!?).

Comment: I met the problem since testing on Chrome and Firefox (Android 7 only). I tried to switch _UseSubmitBehavior_ value to _True/False_ but no lucky. So I guess it bases on the form tag, not button type (it renders the button as _<input type='submit'>_ or _<input type='button'>_)